# CSS flexbox : Whats wrong with my CSS Code?

Tags: css, flexbox

First of all, I know my problem might sounds simple for most of the SOF user's but for me it isn't (you must know that I'm a beginner in HTML & CSS).

I'm doing some exercises to train myself and i'm stuck at the very end of this one :

The last question of my flexbox exercise:

[image: the last question of my flexbox exercise]

```css
#pond {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
  
}
```

What I'm sure is that a selector or maybe a propriety is missing. But I cannot figure which one is missing.

Could you please let me know if the beginning of my css is OK without giving a ready-made answer? I know it won't help myself.
I've just need a kind of boost from you ;-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read [ask] "again"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I was needed help to align frogs on nenuphars with flexbox CSS. Finally, I've noticed I forgot a propriety in my css. In my code, I've added to flex-flow a wrap-reverse instead of a wrap.
Here is the solution :

```css
#pond {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column-reverse wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-between;
  
}
```

:-)